# Listview click listener inside Item is not working in bottom sheet

Tags: android, listview, bottom-sheet

I have a listview and that is inside the Bottomsheet. Everything is working fine. But now I have changed the design of listview Item Now I have Listview with two text view and one image view that will be dealt as a delete button.

**list_item.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLocationName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/wrapped_ic_clear"
                android:focusable="false"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLocationAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and inside getview I am doing this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    final LocationServiceModel mModel = getItem(position);

    //Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        //If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceLayout, parent, false);

        viewHolder.tvLocationName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocationName);
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocationAddress);

        viewHolder.ivDelete = (AppCompatImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        viewHolder.llContainer= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }






    viewHolder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onDeleteFavoriteStore(mModel);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onFavoriteStoreItemClick(mModel);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.tvLocationName.setText(mModel.getFriendlyName() + "");

    if(mModel.getAddress()!=null && !mModel.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress.setText(mModel.getAddress());
    }else {
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress.setText("");
    }


    return convertView;
}




private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvLocationName, tvLocationAddress;
    AppCompatImageView ivDelete;

    LinearLayout llContainer;
}
```

listview

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvLocations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:minHeight="200dp"
   />
```

> **But my click event is not working.**

I have tried using some solutions from SO and that is to use following properties

- android:focusable="false"
- android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

but non of them is working for me.

**What I want:**

> I want to make a listview with the item that has basically 2 click listener.

1. Delete event> When User clicks on Image view (right alligned in item)
2. Edit Event> When user click anywhere in item except image view that will be used to initiate Delete event.

Comment: pls, remove  android:focusable="false" from image view

Comment: if you want to edit anywhere in item then add click event on  your "llContainer"  LinearLayout

Comment: try add android:clicklable="true" to the root relative layout of list_item

Comment: Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to item root .

Comment: @GaneshPatil removing focusable is not helping

Comment: can you pls paste Listview xml file

Comment: @GaneshPatil Yes I have tried this . its not working also

Comment: he is asking for xml file wherein your listview is there, not its item xml

Comment: @GaneshPatil updated

Comment: can you please share more code means adapter class and your list data item model class

Comment: your LinearLayout `id`  `llFavStore` is not in your xml

Comment: @JayDwivedi already posted important piece of code. what more you want me to post ?

Comment: @vikassingh updated id.

Comment: hope the below link will help you http://www.migapro.com/click-events-listview-gridview/   and always share layout screen shot when asking this type of questions

Comment: you got any fix ?

Comment: @SharartiKAKA no still no lcuk

Comment: are you using any motion/clickevent or any touch listeners

Comment: yes there is some implementations

Answer (score 1):

I think as you indicated you have implementations of Motion/Touch events, I have some tips for you.

I am afraid that you are consuming touch event in your implementation. You need to return the false. So that the other work gets carry on.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
return false;
}
```

Please check, if you are making this mistake of returning true. This will indicate that you have consumed the event and no further actions to be carried on. Remove this and return false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make parent layout of ListView clickable and focusable to true

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

**botton_sheet_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dashBoard_bottomSheetContainer_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
   app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

After that, make listview rowlayout clickable and focusable and delete imageview clickable and focusable.

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLocationName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=""
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/wrapped_ic_clear"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLocationAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/secondary_text"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In adapter do this,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    final LocationServiceModel mModel = getItem(position);

    //Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
    if (convertView == null) {
        //If there's no view to re-use, inflate a brand new view for row
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceLayout, parent, false);

        viewHolder.tvLocationName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocationName);
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocationAddress);

        viewHolder.ivDelete = (AppCompatImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);
        viewHolder.llContainer= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llContainer);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // View is being recycled, retrieve the viewHolder object from tag
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }






    viewHolder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.llContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.tvLocationName.setText(mModel.getFriendlyName() + "");

    if(mModel.getAddress()!=null && !mModel.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress.setText(mModel.getAddress());
    }else {
        viewHolder.tvLocationAddress.setText("");
    }


    return convertView;
}




private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvLocationName, tvLocationAddress;
    AppCompatImageView ivDelete;

    LinearLayout llContainer;
}
```

Add onItemClickListener on ListViw in your activity.

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvLocations);

///set your adaper here

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == R.id.ivDelete) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete Item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
});
```

Actually performItemClick() function will trigger the onItemClick() function in listView.